# mono, shell scripting?

Tags: shell, mono

csharp ( version Mono C# compiler version 4.0.0.0) allow to write [C# scripts](http://www.meebey.net/posts/the_big_split_mono_2.10_debian_packaging/), like

```
#!/usr/bin/csharp

Console.WriteLine( "Hello world !" );
```

I tried to add a main() function, but got parsing errors, like

```
{interactive}(1,9): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting `,', `;', or `='
```

Are there docs about this scripting ?

Does it allow use of functions?

Comment: Apparently not. The keywords `static` and `class` aren't acceptable while `using` works. It seems to be a line-by-line parser only, for loops etc. allowed.

Comment: For some reason I can't use csharp for shell scripting on a Mac, any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a newer version of mono/csharp: either wait for a new release of mono 2.11.x/2.12.x or compile it yourself from git. That allows you to define classes interactively.

Comment: Is it possible to use mono/csharp for shell scripting on a Mac? I have the mono framework and Visual Studio for Mac. Thanks.