# MonoDevelop Failure "Unknown MSBuild Failure" on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop

I just installed MonoDevelop on my Ubuntu machine, and attemtepted to run a hello world, just to test it out:

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World");
    }
}
```

...but when building it gives an "Unknown MSBuild failure" error

I have tested Mono before using MonoDevelop and verified that it works.

Comment: what version of Mono? what version of MonoDevelop? what version of Ubuntu? how did you install Mono and MonoDevelop? thanks

Comment: Mono v4.2.3, MonoDevelop v5.10 and Ubuntu 16.04. Installed both Mono and MonoDevelop via apt-get. Sorry for not providing that info initially

Comment: can you now add a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: There you go: http://pasteboard.co/Oz643zU.png

Comment: can you run monodevelop from the command line, and, build your project again? maybe you get more information about the build failure in the console

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to an error or errors during compilation, which oddly enough, MonoDevelop is not telling you.

Assuming you have mono itself installed, open a terminal and compile from there([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392243/run-c-sharp-code-on-linux-terminal)):

```
mcs HelloWorld.cs
```

Comment: I had the same issue. mcs [filename] just gives blank output and then the next prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue with a project that used to work - it seems error is in the package NUnit, however I have not yet found a solution for it - have a look at your packages, perhaps you find your issue there