# Can we call or execute C# Source code from Bash Script?

Tags: c#, linux, bash, mono, execute

The only question i need an answer to is can we use *.cs files or run *.exe files created by Microsoft Visual Studio from Bash Script or Linux Command Prompt?

Comment: You can run C# script. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371560/mono-shell-scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371560/mono-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 3):

You can run .NET exe files created with `Mono on Linux` with the following statement in the command prompt:

```
mono myprogram.exe
```

An executable created with `Visual Studio on Windows` is not runnable by Mono. As @AWSLC suggested you could run it with something like Wine using a command like:

```
wine myprogram.exe
```

If you are using Wine, have in mind that it is a compatibility layer on top of linux, so i would recommend Mono as a safer approach.

If you are starting with a .cs file, you cannot run it with mono since obviously that is not an executable. You can compile it first with the following command:

```
mcs myprogram.cs
```

If the .cs code generated in Visual Studio is compatible with the Mono framework the compiler will generate an exe file which you can run with the `mono` command above.

Comment: .net exe files created on windows are however runnable by mono, and vica versa (assuming they don't use any platform specific stuff).

Answer (score 2):

Today, using .NET Core you can execute #C code form Windows and Linux command-line or script. For example:

test.cs

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

console

```
>dotnet script test.cs
Hello World
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot run *.cs file unless you build them with a .NET compiler.

*.exe files can only be run on windows machines, unless you use an application like wine on linux to emulate windows programs.

It is however possible with a compiler like mono to compile *.cs files to a binary that can be executed on linux and mac machines.

Comment: with mono, you can execute c# exe on linux

Comment: Yes, but only exe's created with mono.

Answer (score -1):

You can't execute the exe directly, but you could use something like [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/) to run it.

Comment: with mono, you can execute c# exe on linux